If p is prime then J = $\left \langle p, a + \sqrt{D} \right \rangle_{\mathbb{Z}}$ is ideal prime.
I try to show that let D $\neq$ 1 and free squares, $a,p,D \in \mathbb{Z}$ also $a^{2} = D \mod p$ then if p is prime then J = $\left \langle p, a + \sqrt{D} \right \rangle_{\mathbb{Z}} = \left \{  \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i s_i : n \in \mathbb{N}, s_i \in \mathbb{Z}, a_i \in \{p, a + \sqrt{D}\}  \right \} $ is ideal prime in $\mathbb{Z}[ \sqrt{D}]$,
My steps:
I try show that $\frac{Z[\sqrt{D}]}{J} \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ in this case $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is domain when p is prime then $J$ is a ideal prime, then for show  $\frac{Z[\sqrt{D}]}{J} \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$  first in case $a = kp$ with k integer, then $\frac{Z[\sqrt{D}]}{\left \langle p, \sqrt{D} \right \rangle} \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$, in other case $mcd(a,p) = 1$, then let any element $a_1+b_1 \sqrt{D}$ of the ring, then all element of ring it's congruent to $a_1+b_1 \sqrt{D} \mod  \langle p \rangle$, with $a_1,b_1$ in ${0,1,.., p-1}$, also $a + \sqrt{D} \equiv 0 \mod J $, thus every element it's $0,1,..., p-1 \mod J$,
Would it be correct this way?

What does the $\langle\cdot\rangle_{\mathbb Z}$ mean? Just the additive abelian group generated by these elements?

If it means the abelian group, you first have to prove it is an ideal before you can take the quotient $\mathbb Z[\sqrt D]/J$ makes sense as a ring

It's true, I proved that it is an ideal in case $a^{2} = D mod p$

Well! You haven't proven it here, and you still have t explained the notation $\langle\cdot\rangle_{\mathbb Z},$ which is unusual notation, so, unless you define it, your question is incomplete.

And $a^2\equiv D\pmod p$ is not a condition of the problem.

@ThomasAndrews Add the observations, thank you. I didn't realize that I didn't set those conditions.

Your description of $J$ agrees with the more concise description $J = {\mathbf Z}p + \mathbf Z(a+\sqrt{D})$: it's the $\mathbf Z$-linear combinations of $p$ and $a+\sqrt{D}$.
You should first prove this set ${\mathbf Z}p + \mathbf Z(a+\sqrt{D})$ is an ideal: it is obviously an additive subgroup of $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{D}]$. Show $\sqrt{D}J \subset J$.
Compare $J$ with $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{D}]$, written as $\mathbf Z + \mathbf Z(a+\sqrt{D})$, to see that $J$ has index $p$ in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{D}]$. Then show any ideal with prime index in a commutative ring is a prime ideal.
